# ARM Microsoft.Web/sites "kind" Possible Values

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Does anyone know what the possible values are for `kind` on a `Microsoft.Web/sites` object in an Azure Resource Manager template?

There is no indication what the valid values are, only that it is a string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2019-08-01/sites

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are five possible values, they are `api`, `app`, `app,linux`, `functionapp`, `functionapp,linux`.

**Meaning**:

`api` - api app

`app` - windows web app

`app,linux` - linux web app

`functionapp` - windows function app

`functionapp,linux` - linux function app

---

You could easily check it in the portal -> `App Services` -> `Add filter` -> `Kind`.

[image]

If you are curious, you can also create one and check it in the [resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com/), it will be like below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This seems like these values should exist in the documentation.

Comment: Is anyone aware of this being documented by Microsoft anywhere?

Comment: In the 'meaning' list, you have "app,linux" listed twice (items 3 and 4). Looks like the fourth item should say "functionapp", perhaps?

Comment: I've just found the value 'container' in use.  would love to find a definitive reference.

Answer (score 2):

Found this while looking for the same answer:

| Kind | Resource Type |
| --- | --- |
| `app` | Windows Web app |
| `app,linux` | Linux Web app |
| `app,linux,container` | Linux Container Web app |
| `hyperV` | Windows Container Web App |
| `app,container,windows` | Windows Container Web App |
| `app,linux,kubernetes` | Linux Web App on ARC |
| `app,linux,container,kubernetes` | Linux Container Web App on ARC |
| `functionapp` | Function Code App |
| `functionapp,linux` | Linux Consumption Function app |
| `functionapp,linux,container,kubernetes` | Function Container App on ARC |
| `functionapp,linux,kubernetes` | Function Code App on ARC |

source: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Things_You_Should_Know/kind_property.md